# Subset of an incomplete metric space

Tags: general-topology

Can an incomplete metric space have a complete subset?
For example, is $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ a complete subset of the rationals with the usual euclidean metric?

Comment: Yes to your first question: consider the open unit interval this is clearly not complete but any closed interval contained in it is. No to the second question: take a rational sequence converging to an irrational Number between zero and one - this is a Cauchy sequence with no limit in your space.

Comment: You can always take a finite subset of any incomplete metric space (including the empty set), and it will always be complete.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes, but your example is not correct. Your example is still a subset of the rational numbers, so there are definitely 'holes' in there. For example, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is not in there even though $0 \leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \leq 1$. So you could find a Cauchy sequence of rationals, that converges to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (in the real numbers), but then this sequence will not converge in $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Now, what would be an example? If we simply take $\mathbb{Q} \cup [0,1]$ (where we consider $[0,1]$ as an interval in $\mathbb{R}$), with the Euclidean metric. Then the entire space is incomplete (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is 'missing'), but the subspace $[0,1]$ is complete since it is a subset of the real numbers, which we know are complete.